# Framework/engine for build mobile crossplatform app with camera and gps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, camera, gps

I want to develop a crossplatform app (for instance iOS and Android) and i was looking at the current engines or frameworks like Corona SDK or Partcile SDK but the camera support is not well supported yet or even doesn't have it.

The HTML5 and javascript based frameworks or engines lacks of camera support too.

Do you have any idea to develop this kind of app?. I thought of using the repective sdks, but it doesn't seem to be very efficient to develop and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator has support for the Camera, GPS etc.  I used it for awhile but gave up because like most x-platform stuff it was a few steps behind, going native is a bit of a pain but has major performance and cutting edge advantages.

I hear that [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) is much better now so you might check it out, people also seem to like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/ga1yq5ys/?gclid=CNTPpafBn6oCFYRd5Qod9QZt6w) etc.

Mono (.NET) has a [iPhone](http://ios.xamarin.com/) and [Android](http://android.xamarin.com/) port, they can get you about 1/2 way there but it's a hybrid solution (core logic is portable, UI not so much)

Comment: Thanks, appcelerator seems kinda expensive... i'm gonna try with phonegap for now wich has MIT and BSD licence  =)

Comment: @FranciscoAlexis Appcelerator used to be free, they only charged for support, if that's changed it's new to me but I have not even looked at it for that last 6 months. I know they bought a IDE type of thing, so maybe they are trying to pay for that acquisition :-)